# Whitelabel chat system to embed in custom made SaaS CRM

Tags: library, software-development, chat, saas

I've developed a simple CRM software that I'm distributing as SaaS product, the CRM creates proposals and quotes.
**I'm looking to integrate a chat system within our CRM**. This chat functionality will enable our users to engage in real-time conversations with their customers who are reviewing quotes and have additional questions or inquiries.

Rather than reinventing the wheel by developing a chat system from scratch, I've decided to explore the option of embedding a third-party software into our web application. This software would provide a white-label chat system, tailored to our needs and seamlessly integrated into our CRM.

It's important to note that we are solely interested in the chat component, and we do not require features like calls or video calls. While the ability to upload images would be a valuable addition, it is not mandatory for our purposes.

For your reference, I've attached a very simple screenshot that illustrates our vision for the chat backend page within our CRM. We aim for the customer-facing chat bubble to resemble the user-friendly interfaces provided by platforms like Messenger or HubSpot.

[image]

Your insights and recommendations in this regard would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your time, and I look forward to your feedback.

Comment: Did you eant the chat to be accessible from the phones?

Comment: @RohitGupta yes, it's important for the final user to be able to chat using their phones. Thanks!